# How to chagne text TextView from fragment_profile in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, view

In the Firebase code, there is a function `updateUI()` in which I need to change the text **Login** to **Profile** in the `fragment_profile`.`updateUI()` is in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    updateUI(null);
}
private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    Fragment frag = findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_profile); // This is where the mistakes begin
    TextView txt = frag.findViewById(R.id.titleProfile);
    txt.setText("Profile");
}
```

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more, its not that clear now. Thanks

Comment: Directly accessing fragment views like this, while not likely your problem, is kind of counter to the entire idea of fragments.  Fragments should be opaque to the Activity- either the Activity should update a model and tell the fragment to update itself based on that new model state, or the Activity should inform the fragment of events that occurred and the fragment should update itself based on those events.  Having the Activity update the fragment state directly makes it pointless to even have a Fragment, you'd be better off just putting the view right into the Activity.

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I just created a new fragment and made the transitions. Thanks for your answers.